# Batch Script - Find words that contain a certain string withing a file

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a file with a lot of text.
EG

```
Hello
This is my file
this is the end of the file
```

I need a script that will search the file and pull out all words (just the words and not the line into another file) that contain for example the letter e
In this case the new file would look like

```
Hello
file
the
end
the
file
```

It may also need to search for as another example bh. (including the full stop) so a file with the following

```
hello
bh.ah1
my file
the end
```

would produce a file with
bh.ah1

hope this is enough detail

Comment: Sorry there should be line breaks in the file here buy you get the idea. It would be a multi line file

Comment: Your post does not make sense. Also can you edit to show the file format?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "searchfor=bh."

for /f "delims=" %%i in (t.t) do (
  for %%j in (%%i) do (
    echo %%j|find "%searchfor%" >nul && echo %%j
  )
)
```

for every line (%%i) do

for every word in this line (%%j) do

if searchstring found then echo word

EDIT to your comment: replace  the `(` with a space in the line, before processing words

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "searchfor=bh."

for /f "delims=" %%i in (t.t) do (
  set t=%%i
  set t=!t:(= !
  for %%j in (!t!) do (
    echo %%j|find "%searchfor%" >nul && echo %%j
  )
)
```

You can do this for more characters with additional lines like `set t=!t:(= !` (replace `(` with )

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. As a follow up to this, some of the strings I am getting back are looking like the following. "prbi_get_hr_reference2_desc(bh.birth_country" I would need to refine this to only give me back the "bh.birth_country" part. Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "target=%~1"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22560073.txt) DO CALL :findem %%a

GOTO :EOF

:findem
SET candidate=%1
IF NOT DEFINED candidate GOTO :EOF 
ECHO %1|FIND /i "%target%" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO(%1
shift
GOTO findem
```

I used a file named `q22560073.txt` for my testing.

To find the text string, use

```
thisbatch text
```

so

```
thisbatch e
```

would find the first list and

```
thisbatch bh.
```

the second.

(I combined both sample testfiles as q22560073.txt)

the `/i` in the `find` command makes the test case-insensitive.

To output to a file, simply use

```
thisbatch text >"filename"
```

where the "rabbits ears" are only required if the filenames contains spaces and other problematic characters, but do no harm in any case.

This should work for a target of any alphabetic or numeric combination plus full stop. It will not work with characters that have a special meaning to `cmd`.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "target=%~1"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22560073.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:(= !"
 SET "line=!line:)= !"
CALL :findem !line!
)

GOTO :EOF

:findem
SET candidate=%1
IF NOT DEFINED candidate GOTO :EOF 
ECHO %1|FIND /i "%target%" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO(%1
shift
GOTO findem
```

revised on further information.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo. As a follow up to this, some of the strings I am getting back are looking like the following. "prbi_get_hr_reference2_desc(bh.birth_country" I would need to refine this to only give me back the "bh.birth_country" part. Is this possible